# Failed to access perforce server when using ingress(Kubernetes) to route the service

Tags: kubernetes, perforce, google-compute-engine

I am getting "partner is not a Perforce client/server" when using ingress to route the service, but I am able to directly query the perforce server in the Kubernetes cluster.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-notls
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: perforce.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: p4-server
          servicePort: 80
```

p4 service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: p4-server
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 1666
      nodePort: 30166
      name: p4-server

  selector: 
    run: p4-server
```

if I am in the cluster:

```
$ p4 -p p4-server:80 info       
User name: root
Client name: platform-3101934619-wtxs5
Client host: platform-3101934619-wtxs5
Client unknown.
Current directory: /
Peer address: 10.4.0.218:49924
Client address: 10.4.0.218
Server address: p4-server-1400441787-fcmd9:1666
Server root: /codelingo
Server date: 2017/10/04 02:19:17 +0000 UTC
Server uptime: 380:53:52
Server version: P4D/LINUX26X86_64/2017.1/1511680 (2017/05/05)
Server license: none
Case Handling: sensitive
```

p4 logs:

```
Perforce server info:
    2017/10/04 02:19:17 pid 23038 root@platform-3101934619-wtxs5 10.4.0.218 [p4/2017.1/LINUX26X86_64/1511680] 'user-info'
```

Failed attempt via ingress:

```
$ p4 -p perforce.domain.com:80 info 
(hangs)
```

p4 logs:

```
Perforce server error:
    Date 2017/10/04 02:18:30:
    Pid 23012
    Connection from 10.4.0.1:38622 broken.
    RpcTransport: partner is not a Perforce client/server.
    RpcTransport: partner is not a Perforce client/server.
    RpcTransport: partner is not a Perforce client/server.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Peer address: 10.4.0.218:49924

looks suspiciously like a bi-directional protocol, meaning that client and server expect to have unfettered access to one another, ala (non-passive mode) ftp

`http:
      paths:
      - path: /*`

I don't believe that `http:` stanza is an accurate statement, as I doubt super, super seriously that Perforce speaks http between the client and the server. There are ongoing discussions around teaching Ingress about TCP, but for the time being I think you've gotten most of the way to where you want to go by already having a `NodePort` for :1666

Create a GCE **tcp** load balancer (which effectively is just a firewall to keep the wild Internet away from your cluster) and point its 1666 to port 30166 on every Node in your cluster. It's unclear if anything further needs to happen around Perforce, but from the "establishing tcp/ip connectivity between outsiders and your in-cluster P4" point of view, I think that would do it

Comment: Perforce does **not** speak http between client and server. It speaks a proprietary TCP application protocol.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was able to create a TCP/IP load balancer and able to access the server via the external IP:1666.  Is this the best I can do, in terms of security? My original intention was to see if I could access the p4 server via http so that I can apply a SSL certificate on the domain/url that points to the p4 server.

Comment: _My original intention was to see if I could access the p4 server via http so that I can apply a SSL certificate_ the game doesn't work like that, as Bryan pointed out. If you want security, enable authentication for Perforce, and if you want to limit the attack surface, use IP restrictions via the GCE load balancer (or, of course, a vpn)